# Can not run multiple servers on nginx

Tags: nginx

0

I have got a server where I want to run one flask web app, and one python socket app. (apps run perfectly)

when I run my nginx, only the 80 port is opened (the web app one).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5859;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

server {
    listen 2556;
    server_name _;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8975;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

I do not know much about nginx, but I did read some of its documentation.

this is what I am trying to achieve: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

I have tried with multiple ports, restarting nginx, reinstalling nginx, and changed the headers multiple times. but none of them worked.

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: It would be helpful to know what error your encounter (`it doesn't work` is not a helpful description).

Comment: There are no error logs, "when i run my nginx, only the 80 port is opened (the web app one)."

Comment: How did you test this? (I find it exceptional that nginx started working with only half its config and said nothing in the error logs - even when it is working normally it logs when it starts)

Comment: it doesn't necessarily have to be in the error logs. If you try to connect to port 2556, what does your client say?

Comment: i have checked by connecting from my client python script, and with this website:
https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

but only the port 80 is being opened

Comment: I think it has to do with my ubuntu version (22.x)

Comment: it hasn't. but we will never know since you are not trying to diagnose it.

Answer (score 0):

Both instances are listening for the same name and the second one to a different port. You can let both listen on the same port, and then use the location proxy to route to the right place. You can [optionally] change the server names, but then you will need to add /etc/hosts entries

```
server { 
listen 80;
server_name flask.app;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5859;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

}
server { 
listen 80;
server_name python.app;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8975;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }

}
```

Comment: So, i cant run my 2 apps on a different port?

Comment: You can, but then you have to access them with the port http://<IP or localhost>:80 and http://<IP or localhost>:2556.
There isn't much advantage to proxying them if you still need to use ports.
You could access them (without nginx) using http://localhost:5859 and http://localhost:8975 - but if you want to access both via port 80 eg. http://flask.app and http://python.app then you need to "name" each instance and proxy them.
You would also need to add something like
`sudo printf "localhost flask.app\nlocalhost python.app" >> /etc/hosts`

Comment: Right, but i want them to run on the internet, not in local.

Comment: You can use something like freedns to point the domains to your IP, then you can have a subdomain for each one similar to the /etc/hosts entry. 
eg. mypythonapp.freedns.org & myflaskapp.freedns.org
Then when a user goes to http://mypythonapp.freedns.org their request will be sent to your public (router) IP address, and nginx will proxy the request from there to your localhost:5859 to match the server_name which you'll have to set to match those names in the above nginx.conf
eg. `server_name mypythonapp.freedns.org;`

Comment: "but i want them to run on the internet" - its a good idea to explain WHAT YOU ARE TRYING TO ACHIEVE in your question. Running webservers on non-standard ports on the internet is a bad idea; a lot of people simply won't be able to connect, and you'll get a bad reputation in SEO.

Comment: Im not running a webserver on the port 2556, its a socket.
im trying to forward the ports 80 and 2556

Answer (score -2):

Ok i've managed to solve the problem this is what i did:

- Install a new ubuntu version (20.04, before i had the 22.04)
- run sudo apt update
- install nginx
- it worked

so leason learned, never use ubuntu 22.04